# If $a,b\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, then $ab\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The **Second Order Property of $\mathbb R$** states that:

If $a,b\in\mathbb R^+$, then $ab\in\mathbb R^+$

However, is the following also true?

If $a,b\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, then $ab\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$

Intuitively, it certainly seems to be true. And if it indeed is true, how to prove it?

Comment: Where exactly you're confused to prove $a,b\geqslant0\Rightarrow ab\geqslant0$? This proposition is trivial.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Proving "trivial" claims from given axioms can be quite nontrivial.

Comment: Yes, it is true. The proof can be done by cases.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen So you understand my concern. Could you give me some more hint? If possible, please write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb R_{\ge0}$ partitions into two subsets, $\mathbb R^+$ and $\{0\}$. Each of $a$ and $b$ is in exactly one of these subsets.

If $a,b\in\mathbb R^+$, then by the given property $ab\in\mathbb R^+\subset\mathbb R_{\ge0}$. If $a\in\{0\}$, $a=0$ and thus $ab=0\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, and similarly for $b\in\{0\}$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. I am a beginner in mathematical formalism so I trip up sometimes in trivial things.